# How to natively increment a dictionary element's value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

When working with Python 3 dictionaries, I keep having to do something like this:

```
d=dict()
if 'k' in d:
    d['k']+=1
else:
    d['k']=0
```

I seem to remember there being a native way to do this, but was looking through the documentation and couldn't find it. Do you know what this is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the use case for [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), here simply using the `int` callable for the default factory.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {})
>>> d['k'] +=1
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'k': 1})
```

A `defaultdict` is configured to create items whenever a missing key is searched. You provide it with a callable (here `int()`) which it uses to produce a default value whenever the lookup with `__getitem__` is passed a key that does not exist. This callable is stored in an instance attribute called `default_factory`.

If you don't provide a `default_factory`, you'll get a `KeyError` as per usual for missing keys.

Then suppose you wanted a different default value, perhaps 1 instead of 0. You would simply have to pass a callable that provides your desired starting value, in this case very trivially

```
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: 1)
```

This could obviously also be any regular named function.

---

It's worth noting however that if in your case you are attempting to just use a dictionary to store the count of particular values, a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is more suitable for the job.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('kangaroo')
Counter({'a': 2, 'o': 2, 'n': 1, 'r': 1, 'k': 1, 'g': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Take note that you can always remove the clutter from the `if` stamemt by using it in an expression:

```
d['k'] = d['k'] + 1 if 'k' in d else 0
```